# Using cached SVG without CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, sprite, gulp

from the numerous searches I'v performed regarding SVG's, I cannot find a solution without having to compromise. I would like :

1- **an external SVG file**: grouping separates SVG icons (Sprite or Stacks), as this reduces the number of HTTP requests, and uses the cache.

2- **simple HTML declaration**, using limited volume to keep readable structure (eg : no inline...).

3- **no setting in HTML** like size, viewbox, or else. Everything should be done in CSS or SVG

4- **ability to manipulate SVG** for all kind of interactivity : CSS, scripts, etc

The closest solution I found was to define each separate icon in the SVG sprite inside a  elements, with Viewbox attribute, then use something like

```
<svg class="myIcon">
     <use xlink:href="#mySymbol"></use>
</svg>
```

in the SVG : the id="mySymbol" is coupled with the viewbox and display the required part of the sprite.
in the CSS : I can prepare transformation and :hover properties...

However I first need to inlude the SVG sprite with inline code before, which cannot be cached. I try to use :

```
<object data="mySVGsprite.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

just at the top of , but that does not work... Has anyone a solution fullfiling all these points ? Joker : I would love to automate a process using GULP + SASS.
thanks in advance.

Bertrand

Comment: [**SVGfor Everybody**](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody)

Comment: cheers. It seems to do what I need, I'll give it a try. As the script is not needed for all browser, I guess I can include it in a <!--[if lte IE 8 ]--> (or something close to this... I haven't studied it yet...)